# How do I reference a custom tag path in cfImport?

Tags: jar, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfimport

I'm trying to add CFGroovy to one of my web applications. I added the jar (which I renamed to cfgroovy.jar) to what I believe is our custom tags directory:

```
C:\JRun4\servers\DDDI\cfusion.ear\cfusion.war\WEB-INF\cfusion\CustomTags
```

Our Sys Admin showed me that that path is currently in our "Extensions > Custom Tag Paths" in the Admin Console. Now I want to use it. So I'd use a `cfimport` tag, but I don't know what goes in the `taglib` attribute:

```
<cfimport prefix="groovy" tagLib="XXXXX">
```

I'm sure it's simple I just have no clue, and I can't find any clear documentation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Adobe Coldfusion Docs page](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_i_04.html)? It looks like its a path relative to the webroot to the file location of the JAR file.

If your CustomTags directory is not in the web root, you may want to make a new mapping in the ColdFusion admin to the folder the JAR is in (or a different folder - I'm not sure if putting the CustomTags in the web root is a good idea, security-wise).

Comment: This was the fix. I had figured it out but a new problem made forget about this. Now it's saying I need a TLD (Tag Library Descriptor). However none exists for this Tag Library, and to my knowledge other users (Ben Nadel for one, I believe) have gotten it working without one.